# Opening WebStorm from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, webstorm

When using the terminal on a Mac on I can use `wstorm .` to open WebStorm and load up the folder that I am currently in.

When I am on a PC the command `wstorm` is not recognized. I am using WebStorm 2016.2 and although I can search for Command-Line Launcher:

[image: Search results for command line launcher]

When I select the command nothing happens.  It is almost like the feature has been removed.

How do I setup PowerShell to open WebStorm 2016.2 to my current directory?

Comment: **1)** `wstorm` is for Mac/Linux -- that "Create Command-line Launcher" action does just that and only available on Linux/Mac. **2)** On Windows you have to use `webstorm` and add path to `webstorm.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable ... or create some alias that will do just that (PowerShell have commands for aliases).

Comment: **3)** AFAIK on Windows just `.` will not work -- you have to use full path to the folder.... The `wstorm` is a python script (AFAIK) that can process `.` and just local folder name and convert it into full path which then passed to the WebStorm's main executable. Since such command is absent on Windows .. you may need to create your own `wstorm.cmd` (or whatever) that would perform that for you.

Comment: P.S. Alias for `webstorm.exe` can be created using this sort of PowerShell command: `set-alias wstorm C:\Program Files\jetbrains\webstorm\bin\WebStorm.exe`